# Values from elements that creates concentric square on distance "k" in NumPy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, square, matrix-indexing

What is the fastest way to get values from elements that creates concentric square on some distance K from the center. I wrote code where I access every element value with `numpy.ndarray.item`, but it has shown poor results. To help you visualize concentric squares here is [picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7ofd.png)

**Note**:

If center of sqaures is on that position that not all of square elements are in matrix then only visible elements shoud count. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuTbo.png)

Even **better solution** will be if I can get sum of elements after `numpy.isclose` method on array of elements from concentric square.

Here is current code:

```
def valid_pixel(image, pixel):
    """
    Returns True if pixel is inside the image boundaries.
    """
    width, height = image.shape
    x, y = pixel
    return 0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height


def calculate_delta(indexed_img, C, k, pixel, h):
    """
    Returns sum of elements all over the distance k that have the same value as parameter C
    """
    x, y = pixel
    c_sum = 0
    v = 1 - h
    for i in range(0, k + 1):
        new_pixel = (x + h * i, y + v * i)
        if valid_pixel(indexed_img, new_pixel) and C == indexed_img.item(new_pixel):
            c_sum += 1
    return c_sum


def color_correlation(indexed_img, colors_map, Ci, Cj, k):
    correl_sum = 0
    for x, y in colors_map.get(Ci, iter(())):
        # this part of code returns sum of elements which create square with center in (x,y) and have the same value as parameter Cj 
        correl_sum += calculate_delta(indexed_img, Cj, 2 * k, (x - k, y + k), 1) + \
                      calculate_delta(indexed_img, Cj, 2 * k, (x - k, y - k), 1) + \
                      calculate_delta(indexed_img, Cj, 2 * k - 2, (x - k, y - k + 1), 0) + \
                      calculate_delta(indexed_img, Cj, 2 * k - 2, (x + k, y - k + 1), 0)

    return correl_sum
```

Comment: Please post your code. This link to [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will demonstrate how to format your code.

Comment: I have added my code. I hope that comments in code will help you. Tnx in advance